# Update global variable

Tags: jquery

I need some help here. I'm trying to make my own content slider writing my own code but can't seem to figure this out. I am new and learning all this, so any help would be appreciated. What i'm trying to do is when the user clicks next, it will hide the current slide and display the next. I'm trying to do this with a global variable, but i'm not sure how to maintain the global variable being updated from within the function. Here is some code, I know my explanation isn't very good.

```
$(function () {


    var i = '';

    $('.next').click(function() {
        $('.slide' + i).hide();
        i++;
        console.log(i);
        if(i <= 4) {
        $('.slide' + i).show();
        }
        else {
        var i = 1;
        $('.slide' + i).show();
        i++;
        console.log(i);
        }
    });

});
```

and the markup

```
<div class="outerWrapper wrapperWidthHeight">
    <div class="innerWrapper wrapperWidthHeight slide1">
    1
    </div>
    <div class="innerWrapper wrapperWidthHeight slide2">
    2
    </div>
    <div class="innerWrapper wrapperWidthHeight slide3">
    3
    </div>
    <div class="innerWrapper wrapperWidthHeight slide4">
    4
    </div>
</div>
<div class="next">NEXT</div>
```

and the CSS

```
.wrapperWidthHeight {
    margin:auto;
    width:900px;
    height:600px;
    }

.outerWrapper {
    overflow:hidden;
    position:relative;
    margin-top:10px;
    border:1px solid black;
    border-radius:15px;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px 5px #888;
    }

.innerWrapper {
    position:absolute;
    text-align:center;
    padding:0;
    margin:auto;
    }


.slide1 {
    display:block;
    }

.slide2, .slide3, .slide4 {
    display:none;
    }

.next{
    display:block;
    margin:auto;
    }
```

Comment: You should assign an initial value of 1 to `i` so that then you can increment it.

Comment: anything in your error console?  I expect it will be giving an error as per the other suggestions about you not initialing your variable to a number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a couple tweaks to what you had got it working for me:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var i = 1;

    $('.next').click(function () {
        $('.slide' + i).hide();
        i++;
        console.log(i);
        if (i <= 4) {
            $('.slide' + i).show();
        }
        else {
            i = 1;
            $('.slide' + i).show();
            console.log(i);
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: Please note the *important* bit .. which is *removing the `var` from before `i` in the inner function*. (Otherwise, with the subsequent `var i`, the nested `i` is a "shadow" variable.)

Comment: This worked for me perfectly. It seems I forgot the $(document.ready( portion as I always do for some reason. I originally had var i = 1; but this seemed to always reset to 1 after the initial click. 
I will flag this as the answer when time passes. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you for that pointer as well. I have a lot to learn, but this site has been great!

Comment: @Aosto That conclusion is wrong. The form: `jQuery(fn)` is equivalent to `$(document).ready(fn)` and is just a style choice. The problem is that `var i` inside the inner-most function created a shadow (a new local variable binding with the same name) that "hid" the outer `i` variable.

Comment: Okay, thank you again. As I said, i'm relatively new to all of this and have just started trying to write my own code as apposed to using snippets from other people to better my understanding.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function () {

    var i = 1;   // should be a number
    // this var IS NOT global, nut it is available to
    // the scope of the anonymous function

    $('.next').click(function() {
        // accessing i here is only accessing via
        // the scope chain, i isn't "global" this way

        $('.slide' + i).hide();
        i++;
        console.log(i);

        if(i > 4) {
           i = 1;  // DON'T write "var" here, doing so
                   // defines a NEW local variable i in the local scope
        }

        $('.slide' + i).show();
        // you don't need to increment i here,
        // it's already incremented by setting from 4+ to 1
        console.log(i);
    });
});​
```

Answer (score 0):

Try creating your global variable as a member of the window object, outside of your function.
You can put something like this, just outside of your function:

```
window.i = 0;
```

if you're going to increment it, you should also probably initialize it to zero, instead of an empty string, I'm not saying it will cause a problem, just that it's good practice.

Comment: He/she already *almost* has closures done correctly - why go back to an old window.junk approach?